# regex should contain only

Tags: regex

1. I have a config file that should contain all allowed ip addresses and should NOT contain any extra ip addresses.For eg: if 10.1.1.51, 10.1.1.61 and EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3 are the allowed ip addreses then the config file would look like:
   logging host 10.1.1.51
   logging host 10.1.1.61
   logging host ipv6 EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3
2. The order of listing the ip addresses is not important
3. The ip address can be in either ipv4 or ipv6 format.For ipv6 foramt it
       should be preceeded with string ipv6 as shown in above example
4. Each ip address is listed in a new line beginning with strings
   logging host as shown in above example
5. The regex flavour is Java.

Can you figure out a java regex to fit all these conditions??
If not possible to achieve with one regex the answer can have two regexes:one that fits the positive condition of should contan all allowed ip and a second condition of should not contain any other ip.

I am still struggling to come up with one regex but i can think of the negative condition as below:

```
^logging host (?!10.1.1.51|10.1.1.61|ipv6 EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3)
```

Edit:Further clarification post Berto's answer:
The answer should make sure that all the three allowed ip addresses in my question are all listed and listed each in a seperate line and can be listed in any order and no extra line with an ip other than the three allowed ips be listed.
For eg: if the file contains the following it is invalid because it does contain all the three allowed ip but also contains a fourth line that has an unallowed ip:
logging host 10.1.1.51
logging host 10.1.1.61
logging host ipv6 EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3
logginh host 10.1.1.71

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^logging host (([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})|(ipv6 [A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}))
```

There are obviously shorter REGEX that will do it.
However i don't know what you mean with `EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3` because IPV6 has 8 groups, separated by a colon, of 4 hexadecimal digits

Comment: Thanks Berto.This answer checks for validity of ip address but does not make sure that all the three allowed ip addresses in my question are all listed and listed each in a sererate line and no ip other than the three allowed ips is listed.

Comment: @pradeepk6 so you want only those 3 ips?

Comment: @pradeepk6 ok i see, so you want to check whether that file contains those ip and only those ip, in separate lines, and not repeated, am I right?

Comment: @pradeepk6 is there a specific reason why you want to use REGEX?..